# stop the code from getting executed after a jconformation dialog is closed with cancel option

Tags: java

I am trying to conform some message with the user and if he sayes he is sure the code written should execute but if he refuses the jconformation box the code should not be executed in my case even if i cancel or press no the code still gets executed and the data gets committed. what can i do to stop this my code is given below...

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(evt.getSource()==jButton1){
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Are You Sure You Want to Submit This Data and Genertate a New Remittance Id!");

                DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
        try {

            Connection con = util.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dbo.bk_det(rm_id,bk_name,bk_branch,bk_add,bk_ref,ref_dt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            String rm = (tf_rm_id.getText().trim() == null || tf_rm_id.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : tf_rm_id.getText();
            Object bkn = (cb_bkname.getSelectedItem() == null || cb_bkname.getSelectedItem().equals("")) ? "NILL" : cb_bkname.getSelectedItem();
            Object bkbn = (cb_brname.getSelectedItem() == null || cb_brname.getSelectedItem().equals("")) ? "NILL" : cb_brname.getSelectedItem();
            Object bkpln = (cb_plname.getSelectedItem() == null || cb_plname.getSelectedItem().equals("")) ? "NILL" : cb_plname.getSelectedItem();
            String rf = (tb_bkref.getText().trim() == null || tb_bkref.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tb_bkref.getText();
            String rfdt = (tf_refdt.getText().trim() == null || tf_refdt.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_refdt.getText();
            stmt.setString(1, ""+(rm));
            stmt.setString(2, ""+(bkn));
            stmt.setString(3, ""+(bkbn));
            stmt.setString(4, ""+(bkpln));
            stmt.setString(5, ""+(rf));
            stmt.setString(6, ""+(rfdt));
            stmt.execute();

            PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bk_rep(rm_id, br_name, br_desig, br_pf, dt_rep, mob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            String rm1 = (tf_rm_id.getText().trim() == null || tf_rm_id.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : tf_rm_id.getText();
            String brn = (tfbrname.getText().trim() == null || tfbrname.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tfbrname.getText();
            String brpf = (tf_brpf.getText().trim() == null || tf_brpf.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_brpf.getText();
            String brdes = (tf_brdes.getText().trim() == null || tf_brdes.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_brdes.getText();
            String brdtrep = (tf_rm_dt.getText().trim() == null || tf_rm_dt.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_rm_dt.getText();
            String brmob = (tf_brmob.getText().trim() == null || tf_brmob.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_brmob.getText();
            stmt2.setString(1, ""+(rm1));
            stmt2.setString(2, ""+(brn));
            stmt2.setString(3, ""+(brdes));
            stmt2.setString(4, ""+(brpf));
            stmt2.setString(5, ""+(brdtrep));
            stmt2.setString(6, ""+(brmob));

            stmt2.execute();

            PreparedStatement stmt3 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bk_sec([bs_name],[bs_desig],[rm_id],[dt_rep]) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            String rm2 = (tf_rm_id.getText().trim() == null || tf_rm_id.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : tf_rm_id.getText();
            String sn = (tfsname.getText().trim() == null || tfsname.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tfsname.getText();
            String sdes = (tf_sdes.getText().trim() == null || tf_sdes.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_sdes.getText();
            String bsdtrep = (tf_rm_dt.getText().trim() == null || tf_rm_dt.getText().equals("")) ? "NILL" : tf_rm_dt.getText();



            stmt3.setString(1, ""+(sn));
            stmt3.setString(2, ""+(sdes));
            stmt3.setString(3, ""+(rm2));
            stmt3.setString(4, ""+(bsdtrep));


            stmt3.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "COMMITED SUCCESSFULLY!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

        }   
        CalendarUtil cal=new CalendarUtil();
        tf_rm_id.setText(cal.getRemId());
        String datePrefix = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, YYYY").format(new Date());
        tf_rm_dt.setText(datePrefix); 
        tb_bkref.setText("");
        tf_refdt.setText("");
        tf_brpf.setText("");
        tf_brdes.setText("");
        tf_brmob.setText("");
        tfsname.setText("");
        tf_sdes.setText("");
        tfbrname.setText("");
        tf_scity.setText("");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would have a closer look to the showConfirmDialog, you would have seen it is returning an Integer. i will quote the API for the return.

`Returns:
an integer indicating the option selected by the user`

the return should be the order of the Buttons, you got in the confirm dialog, so it should be 2 in your case.

You just need to have an if statement now, which checks this value

you can do it like this:

```
int buffer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Are You Sure You Want to Submit This Data and Genertate a New Remittance Id!")

// user pressed yes
if(buffer == 0) {
    try {
        // whatever
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
else if(buffer == 1) {
     // user input = no
}

else if(buffer == 2) {
     // user input = cancel
}
```

Comment: then where should i write my code of execution in the if statement or in the else part??

Comment: you got the following integers for your confirm dialog:
`0 = yes`
`1 = no`
`2 = cancel`

i will edit my answer for you